# mouse movement controlled by webdrive behaves differently in script and interpreter mode, why?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, mouse

I have a function hover() as below, dr is a firefox driver, image is a locator value.
If I run the function in an interpreter mode against a specific page, some more elements will display; but if I run the function in a script, I can't see the elements appear.

```
def hover():
    elem=dr.find_element_by_css_selector(image)
    hov=ActionChains(dr).move_to_element(elem)
    hov.perform()
```

I even tried ActionChains(dr).move_by_offset(), or added some time.sleep(1) before and after the hov.perform() statement.  Same results: interactive mode works, script mode fails.
I am using SPE to run the script and interpreter.

Any one has the same experience and solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: well, is it possible that it is your code? if you think it is possible, we would have to see it.

Comment: that is, can the problem occour somewhere in the sript that you havent showed us.

Comment: After a while, even the interpreter mode does not work either. I mean I can't see the elusive elements either way.

Comment: essentially, the same question as this [mouse click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506375/how-to-click-on-windows-menu-which-populate-on-mouse-hover-using-selenium). No answer either.